# Mysql get all records not processed previous month in current month

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains following records

```
slno | FirstName | LastName | Attended | Month  | Year |
-----|-----------|----------|----------|--------|------|
1    |  John     |  Smith   |   0      |   04   | 2017 |
2    |  Jack     |  Paul    |   1      |   04   | 2017 |
3    |  Jerry    |   Tom    |   1      |   04   | 2017 |
4    |  Beth     |  Home    |   0      |   04   | 2017 |
5    |  Julia    |  John    |   1      |   04   | 2017 |
6    |  Cris     |  joy     |   0      |   05   | 2017 |
7    |  Meiy     |  Rony    |   1      |   05   | 2017 |
8    |  Ronald   |   Jony   |   1      |   05   | 2017 |
9    |  Quest    |  Pio     |   0      |   05   | 2017 |
10   |  Mary     |  June    |   1      |   05   | 2017 |
11   |  Joy      |  Meth    |   0      |   03   | 2017 |
12   |  Ruby     |  Rony    |   1      |   03   | 2017 |
13   |  Royal    |   Jony   |   1      |   03   | 2017 |
14   |  Tweet    |  Pio     |   0      |   03   | 2017 |
15   |  Min      |  June    |   1      |   03   | 2017 |
```

I want to show the data based on month and year. 
Eg: 04 2017  should show only April month data and March which is having attended=0. But when i search for 05 2017 , it should show May month data including previous months data which is Attended=0 [march and april].

I have following statement:

```
select FirstName,LastName,Attended from UserTable 
where Attended in (0,1)
and ( Attended not in (1) or (Month='04' and Year='2017'));
```

I will get records what i want. But if i search for Month='03' Year='2017' , it shows all Attended=0 from May as well as from April.

```
if   Month='05' year='2017' -- current month

    6    |  Cris     |  joy     |   0      |   05   | 2017 |
    7    |  Meiy     |  Rony    |   1      |   05   | 2017 |
    8    |  Ronald   |   Jony   |   1      |   05   | 2017 |
    9    |  Quest    |  Pio     |   0      |   05   | 2017 |
    10   |  Mary     |  June    |   1      |   05   | 2017 |
    1    |  John     |  Smith   |   0      |   04   | 2017 |
    4    |  Beth     |  Home    |   0      |   04   | 2017 |
    11   |  Joy      |  Meth    |   0      |   03   | 2017 |
    14   |  Tweet    |  Pio     |   0      |   03   | 2017 |
```

if month='04' year='2017'

```
1    |  John     |  Smith   |   0      |   04   | 2017 |
2    |  Jack     |  Paul    |   1      |   04   | 2017 |
3    |  Jerry    |   Tom    |   1      |   04   | 2017 |
4    |  Beth     |  Home    |   0      |   04   | 2017 |
5    |  Julia    |  John    |   1      |   04   | 2017 |
11   |  Joy      |  Meth    |   0      |   03   | 2017 |
14   |  Tweet    |  Pio     |   0      |   03   | 2017 |
```

if month='03' year='2017'

```
11   |  Joy      |  Meth    |   0      |   03   | 2017 |
12   |  Ruby     |  Rony    |   1      |   03   | 2017 |
13   |  Royal    |   Jony   |   1      |   03   | 2017 |
14   |  Tweet    |  Pio     |   0      |   03   | 2017 |
15   |  Min      |  June    |   1      |   03   | 2017 |
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Could you post your table schema, what is the type of attended, month and year columns?

Comment: varchar it is.  stored procedure calls like this : call getUserDetails('04','2017');

Comment: Edit your question with additional info instead of in a comment. What output do you expect, especially for the previous month info.

Comment: Do you need  any  previous date rows (with `Attended=0`) , or only one previous month (with `Attended=0`) ?

Comment: Previous date row with attended=0... it may be jan/feb/march/april

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE
('05' = `Month` AND '2017' = `Year`) 
OR
(
    '05-2017' >= DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`Mont`, '-', `Year`), '%m-%Y'), '%m-%Y')
    AND
    Attended = 0
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by parsing your month and year as a date, and then query this like this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE
('05' = `Month` AND '2017' = `Year`) 
OR
(
    '05-2017' >= DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`Mont`, '-', `Year`), '%m-%Y'), '%m-%Y')
    AND
    Attended = 0
);
```

Comment: That won't get the current month's info where Attended = 1 or 0

Comment: @SloanThrasher updated the answer to account for that

Comment: Close, ```AND '2017' = Year```